# Dirty (changed) attributes: since when are the values in the changeset strings (instead of objects)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimistic-locking

I'm using optimistic locking to prevent people overwriting each others changes in race conditions.

Since I upgraded Rails from `5.1` to `5.2`, my specs break, and I tracked it down to the fact that in the `changes` array, the changes that are related to a file upload are not any longer `Uploader` elements, but bare strings.

Before:

```
[1] pry(#<User>)> change
=> [
    [0] #<AvatarUploader:0x007fcc7117bc00 # Value before
    [1] #<AvatarUploader:17bc0cc7100x997f # Current value
```

Now:

```
[1] pry(#<User>)> change
=> [
    [0] "image.jpg", # Value before
    [1] "avatar.png" # Current value
]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you add the spec which is erroring to help me understand the issue better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find out why the afore-mentioned behaviour changed, but I could fix it.

Code before:

```rb
@user.changes.map do |attribute, change|
  unless ['updated_at', 'lock_version'].include? attribute
    StaleInfo.new resource:     resource,
                  attribute:    attribute,
                  value_before: change[0],
                  value_after:  change[1]
  end
end
```

Code now:

```rb
@user.changes.map do |attribute, change|
  unless ['updated_at', 'lock_version'].include? attribute
    StaleInfo.new resource:     resource,
                  attribute:    attribute,
                  value_before: resource.class.find(resource.id).send(attribute),
                  value_after:  resource.send(attribute)
  end
end
```

It feels quite quirky this way though, and it needs an additional DB query (to load the original object).

Answer (score 0):

This problem seem similar to other strange issue on Dirty checking in the [CarrierWave 1.3.1](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues)

Try to reinstall the older version or try the 2.0.0 but seem that they haven't yet fix that problem.

Comment: Thank you. Turned out it was not related to CarrierWave, but to Rails.